# Python '==' incorrectly returning false

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a difference of two files line by line, and Python is always returning false; even when I do a diff of the same files, Python (almost) always returns false. Goofy example, but it replicates my problem on Python 3.4.3.

```
file1.txt (example)
1
2
3

file1 = r"pathtofile\file1.txt"
file2 = r"pathtofile\file1.txt"
f1 = open(file1, "r")
f2 = open(file2, "r")

for line1 in f1:
    found = False
    for line2 in f2:
        if repr(line1) == repr(line2):
            found = True
            print("true")
    if found == False:
        print("false")
```

Python correctly identifies that the first line is the same, but everything after that is false. Can anybody else replicate this? Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want `if found == False:` to always execute, you should probably put a `found = True` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Are you trying to detect if two files are identical or if there's any line that's the same? Because you could possibly use the `for else` syntax to do that without needing the `found` variable.

Comment: Also it's more Pythonic to test booleans with `if bool` and `if not bool`

Comment: Kevin, I actually had that in my code and just forgot to bring it over to the question. That's what I get for writing this on my way to lunch, haha. Nice catch!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have exhausted the iterator after the first iteration over `f2`, you need to `file.seek(0)` to go back to the start of the file.

```
for line1 in f1:
    found = False
    for line2 in f2:
        if repr(line1) == repr(line2):
            print("true")
    f2.seek(0) # reset pointer to start of file
```

You only check the first line of `f1` against the lines of `f2`, after the first loop there is nothing to iterate over.

Depending on what you want to happen, you either need to `break` when you find the line that matches or else reset `found = False` in the inner loop.

If you want all the matching lines then just store the output in a list or if the files are not very big you can use sets to find to find common lines.

```
with open("f1") as f1, open("f2") as f2:   
    st = set(f1)
    common = st.intersection(f2)
```

If you want the difference use  `st.difference(f2)`, for lines in either both not in both use  `st.symmetric_difference(f2)`. It all depends on what you actually want to do.

You might also want to check out [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) and [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 2):

As Python reads a file, it actually moves through the file like a cursor. Once it's reached the end, it no longer has any text to read. You'd be better off reading all of `f2` in one go the the `readlines` function. That will read the whole file and store it as a list where each line is an element of the list. Then you can iterate over it as many times as you want.

```
file1 = r"pathtofile\file1.txt"
file2 = r"pathtofile\file1.txt"
f1 = open(file1, "r")
f2 = open(file2, "r").readlines()

for line1 in f1:
    found = False
    for line2 in f2:
        if repr(line1) == repr(line2):
            print("true")
    if found == False:
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other responses, if you just want to find out if the files are the same or not, it would logically be better to compare the files line by line, rather than comparing the 1st line in the 1st file with all the lines of the 2nd file, then comparing the 2nd line in the 1st file with all the lines of the 2nd file etc etc.

For this example it's possible to use the `for-else` clause:

```
for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
    if line1 != line2:
        print ("false")
        break   # found 2 different lines in the same place so the files can't be equal
else:
     print ("true")
```

Comment: The files I'm using actually aren't in the same order, but this is a great suggestion if they were identical. :)